# determining the greatest $n$ for which $3^n$ divides $30!$

Tags: factorial

Determine the greatest integer $n$ such that  $3^n\mid 30!$

I have no idea of how to approach this problem. I would first calculate $30!$ but obviously that number is way too large. Any help?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: How many factors of three can you count in 30!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many factors of $3$ go into $30!$?

To answer this consider how many multiples of $3$s go into $30$, and then how many multiples of $9$s go into $30$, then $27$ etc.

The process above can be expressed as the sum:

\begin{align}
\sum\limits^\infty_{n = 1} \left\lfloor\dfrac{30}{3^n}\right\rfloor & = \left\lfloor\dfrac{30}{3}\right\rfloor +  \left\lfloor\dfrac{30}{9}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{30}{27}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\dfrac{30}{81}\right\rfloor + \cdots \\ & = 10 + 3 + 1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots \\ & = 14.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Consider the multiples of $3$ less than or equal to $30$.

$30=3\times5\times2\\
27=3^3\\
24=3\times2^3\\
21=3\times7\\
18=3^2\times2\\
15=3\times5\\
12=3\times2^2\\
9=3^2\\
6=3\times2\\
3 = 3\times1$

You should count $14$ three's. So $n=14$.

Comment: You don't need to count.

Comment: Wouldn't take more than 10 seconds to do in your head though.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that a number of the form $3^k b$, where $b$ is not divisible by $3$, has to pay a $k$ dollar tax.

So for example $6$ has to pay a $1$ dollar tax, while $18$ has to pay $2$ dollars. And $810$ has to pay $4$ dollars.

We want the **total** tax paid by the numbers $1$ to $30$ inclusive.

The Taxwoman collects the tax in a funny way. First she collects $1$ dollar from all the people who owe tax. So she collects $1$ dollar from all the multiples of $3$ from $1$ to $30$. There are $10=\lfloor 30/3\rfloor$ such numbers. Now she has $\$10$.

Note that $9,18,27$ still owe tax. She goes around and collects $1$ dollar from the $\lfloor 30/3^2\rfloor$ people who still owe tax. She collects $\$3$.

But $27$ still owes tax. She goes around and collects $1$ dollar from the $\lfloor 30/3^3\rfloor$ people who still owe. She gets $\$1$.

Total take: $10+3+1$.

The idea generalizes. Instead of $30$, we can use any positive integer. Instead of $3$, we can use any **prime**.